# Java EE , ¿Como especificar Security Constraints en el WEB.XML de una Aplicación web Java?

Tags: java, java-ee

Al desplegar un servicio en java, se tiene el  descriptor de despliegue WEB.XML con el siguiente código , ¿ Que implicaciones tiene en el consumo del web-service con respecto a restricciones de seguridad  y acceso ?

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>WebService</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL<transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: 261/5000
Advertencia de Google Translate: también hará que el consumo de WSDL requiera autenticación, por lo que, por ejemplo, en la interfaz de usuario de SOAP, deberá ingresar el nombre de usuario y la contraseña. Sin embargo, el usuario final podría recibir una copia del WSDL que podría almacenar localmente.

Comment: De antemano Gracias JGlass, por tu respuesta sin embargo esperaba una definición mas cercana  desde perspectiva del tema  y sus conceptos  "Securing Web Applications " -> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html

Comment: De nada, Fabian, lo siento, no pude ayudar mucho. El enlace que proporcionó es una buena lectura. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

investigando un poco mas encontre lo siguiente:
Esta restricción de seguridad ,es para el recurso de nuestra aplicación web llamado WebService .  Se aplica a  todo sus recursos (/* el patron aplica a todas las url's ) una restricción en el transporte de los datos de tipo CONFINDENCIAL ,de manera que se evita que otras entidades puedan observar el contenido de la transmisión. Haciendo una analogia como usar https
Se puede encontrar mas información en este post https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html